# Gazebo ignition (garden/fortress) attaching model to arm

Tags: robotic-arm, gazebo

I'm trying to attach a moving object with inertia to a robotic arm. I saw that there are plugins for detaching joints but is there a way to do the opposite and attach one model to another via a joint? preferably it would maintain its velocity and angular velocity till acted on by the arm.
If not, then could 2 separate SDF models be designed one with the model attached, then swap one model for the other during simulation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The detachable joint plugin can also attach two models (specifically, links from two different models) together with a fixed joint. Here's [an example](https://github.com/osrf/mbzirc/blob/ec66f35c1fc925f18565c03251bd5f12f5b6b4e3/mbzirc_ign/src/SuctionGripper.cc#L278-L283) of how that's done in code

Comment: cheers thank you I'll check that out.

Comment: Yep, it worked amazingly. Thank you for that, If I could upvote you i would